# How do I get the settings tab in ms crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am new to CRM, I am using MS crm 2011. I wanted to hide the settings tab for only a particular user. I have used the site as shown below and have followed the steps as mentioned.

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/03/22/sitemap-editing-in-crm-2011/

Following these steps made the settings tab disappear for all the users of crm including the admin users. How do I get back the settings tab in ms crm . Please help, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Download the CRM toolbox from here http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/ and use the CRM Site Map Editor.
The tool will help you hide the desired section for a specified security role.

Open the tool, click on Site Map Editor, define the connection to the CRM (IFD, SSL, username, etc).
Then click on Load SiteMap, you will be shown the list of the areas.

Click on Area(Settings) on the left and you will see a new panel on the right. Click on the Show group checkbox.

Comment: Thankyou....Ill download the CRM toolbox. However do you know how to get back the settings tab. Its already hidden and I want to get it back.